# Work is done by the man against gravity in climbing to the top?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work

A $170$ lb man carries a $20$ lb can of paint up a helical staircase that encircles a silo with radius $30$ ft. The silo is $80$ ft high and the man makes exactly four complete revolutions. Suppose there is a hole in the can of paint and $16$ lb of paint leaks steadily out of the can during the man's ascent. How much work is done by the man against gravity in climbing to the top?

---

$F = (170+20) = 190$

Work done = $ \int F.dr = 190 *80 = 15200$ ft-lbs.

How to use the fact that the paint leaks.

Comment: Does the paint leak at a constant rate?

Comment: @Protein The paint leaks out steadily.